# if else with xml tags using bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have csv file that has to convert into xml file. i am stuck at if command where it has to check if name1 is empty go to name2 else name1 element. i tried below but didn't work.I have changed whole if statement in to flower braces - { }, also single quotes - ''-either of it didnt work.

```
id|name1|name2|batch
1||hello|2012

<id>1</id>
<name1>if [[$arr[1] == **]] then $arr[2] else $arr[1]</name1>
<batch>2012</batch>
```

the above command gives me like this which is incorrect

```
    <id>1</id>
    <name1>if [[$arr[1] == **]] then hello else </name1>
    <batch>2012</batch>
```

what i am expecting as output -(since name1 is empty i am checking name2 else it should have name1 only )

```
<id>1</id>
<name1>hello</name1>
<batch>2012</batch>
```

Comment: None of this is Bash or CSV. The code inside the XML isn't syntactically valid. CSVs are *comma* separated values in a table, with the *same number of columns in each row.*

Comment: It looks like you're trying to embed bash inside of XML, which doesn't make any sense (and as @l0b0 said, the bash code itself isn't syntactically valid -- try [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net)).

Comment: shell is a poor choice for this. Use a language like perl, python, etc. with CSV reader and XML builder libraries available. Maybe a template engine...